# How to put values in liked combo boxes in internet explorer using vba

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, combobox

I am trying to fill in a form on a website using VBA.

Problem: The problem is that in the webpage the comboboxes are linked for example if I select a value in the first combobox manually then it activates the next one (which is otherwise greyed out). However, when I try to fill values in the comboboxes using vba in the last line of the below code, the next combobox is still greyed out / inactive. Please help.

```
Sub newabc()

Dim ie As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

ie.Visible = True

ie.navigate "URL"

While ie.Busy
   DoEvents
Wend

ie.Document.getelementbyid("USER").Value = "username"
ie.Document.getelementbyid("PASSWORD").Value = "password"

ie.Document.all("Submit").Click

While ie.Busy
   DoEvents
Wend

ie.navigate "tab"

While ie.Busy
   DoEvents
Wend

ie.Document.all("new").Click

While ie.Busy
   DoEvents
Wend

ie.Document.all("j_id0:frm:jobTrackerPageBlock0:startflds1:repeat5:1:inputField").Value = "Media Payables"

'problem occurs here as the next combo box stays inactive.
```

Comment: Without knowing the source code of the web page it is really hard to answer. Maybe calling `ie.Document.all("j_id0:frm:jobTrackerPageBlock0:startflds1:repeat5:1:inputField").onchange()` after assigning the .Value may help.

Answer (score 1):

Perfect

`ie.Document.all("elementID‌​").onchange` did the trick.
Thank you. I have been trying to figure this out for quite sometime now.
Thanks a ton Axel Richter.